# Is there already a functionality in flutter, that supresses Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, flutter, applepay

I am aware of requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression, however I do not know if anything like this exists within Flutter. Basically: I want to supress the Apple Pay popup when the App is in the Foreground.

Thank you!

Comment: Once you have the entitlement from Apple you can probably just add that line to your AppDelegate. If you want to only suppress Apple Pay at specific times you may need to create your own plugin.